# Custom Search Page layout does not show up in ribbon

Tags: search, page-layout, enterprise-search

I have created 2 test `page layouts` on my search center site collection. One I created via the browser by going to `Site Settings\ Design Manager \ Edit Page layouts \ create a page layout` and the second method was via the `SharePoint 2013 design Manager`. But none of them are showing up in the dropdown in the ribbon?

Why is it not showing up? I have checked it in and there is nothing to be published.

Comment: Found this interesting link: https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/ribbon-missing-from-publishing-pages/
Including the cookie part. Maybe could help you.

Comment: sorry, but I am not missing Ribbons. I created a page layout and that is not showing up in the ribbon.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read correctly. Did you publish and approve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to see your page layout follow these steps:

1. Go to site settings
2. Select **Page layouts and site templates**
3. Under page layouts section select either "**Pages in this site can use any layout**" or "**Pages in this site can only use the following layouts**", 
   if you would like to see specific page layouts and 
   then add your page layout to the right box